# Distance to "equal-distance-locus" within a lune

Tags: geometry

I would like to find the distance function for a curve comprised of all points within a [lune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_(geometry)) that are of equal perpendicular distance to both circular arcs. In other words, what's the minimum distance by which a given point inside of the lune would need to move in order to become equidistant to both arcs? My use case would require both arcs to be of equal radius, if this helps.

Constructing a signed distance function for the lune itself is fairly [straightforward](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/WtdBRS), but this particular problem seems considerably harder. I've been mulling over it for a few days without any real idea of how to approach it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit**

For clarity, the curve marked in red is what I would like to find the distance function of:

[image]

Comment: I don' t understand the difference between your question and the "straightforward" distance function you are refering to. Do you look for a mathematical description instead of a "programmatic" one ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm not looking for the distance to the edge of the lune. What I'm interested in is the curve on which all points are equally far away from both circular arcs that comprise the lune. You can see it in the linked animation where the blue arcs meet at an acute angle. It's difficult to describe and I unfortunately don't know, whether or not there exists a proper technical term for such a curve. My goal is to figure out, how far away any given point within in lune is from *that* curve.

Comment: You will be interested by this [reference](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT668/EMT668.Folders.F97/Norton/Al-Quhi/Tangent_Circles.html). Beware, don't upload anything from this site which is qualified as "non secure".

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you, I'll take a look.

Comment: As you are looking for a "technical term", it is the ["squeleton"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton), or more plainly it could be "lune bissector" by analogy with "line bissector" :)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks, good to know. It seemed like the sort of problem that would have plenty of "prior art," but I just didn't know what to search for. And thanks again for the reference, it was really useful for understanding the geometry behind it.

Comment: Computing the distance function of an ellipse seems to be its own [rabbit hole](https://iquilezles.org/articles/ellipsedist/), but at least it's a bit easier to search for. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume the lune is constructed from the arcs of two circles, one of which is centered at $(-c,0)$, and the other centered at a point $(c,0)$ in the coordinate plane, where $c > 0$.  Let the former (shorter) arc have radius $r_1$ and the latter (longer) $r_2$.

Clearly, the set of points inside the lune that are a distance of $d$ from the first arc is the arc of a circle concentric with the shorter arc whose radius is $r_1 + d$.  Similarly, the set of points inside the lune that are a distance of $d$ from the longer arc is the arc of a circle concentric with the longer arc whose radius is $r_2 - d$.

Therefore, if a point $(x,y)$ is equidistant from the sides of the lune, then the sum of its distances to $(-c,0)$ and $(c,0)$ is $(r_1 + d) + (r_2 - d) = r_1 + r_2$, a constant.  It follows that the locus is an arc of an ellipse whose center is located at the midpoint $(0, 0)$ have foci at $(-c,0)$ and $(c,0)$.  That is to say,

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1,$$

where $$a = \frac{r_1 + r_2}{2}, \quad b = \sqrt{\frac{(r_1 + r_2)^2}{4} - c^2},$$
are the semimajor and semiminor axes, respectively.

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at the reference I have given in a comment ?